# Does SQL Server replication support this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, replication

Suppose I have central site and branch sites. Branch sites also have its own distribution center;

Northern center, Southern center, Western center, and Eastern center.

I would like all information replicate among its own region. But only center site that should have all data in all regions.

Data inserted in each region can be updated only in that region.

Please advice me whether SQL Server supports this scenario, and how to configure it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, SQL Server supports filtered replication publication.  There's a bit to it, but [here's a good place to start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx):

> Replication offers four types of
>   filters:
>
> - Static row filters, which are    available with all types of  replication. Using static row filters, you can choose a subset of rows to be published. All Subscribers to a filtered publication receive the same subset of rows for the filtered  table. For more information, see the section "Static Row Filters" in this topic.
> - Column filters, which are available    with all types of replication. Using  column filters, you can choose a  subset of columns to be published.  For more information, see the section "Column Filters" in this topic.
> - **Parameterized row filters, which are    available only with merge replication. Using parameterized row filters, you can choose a subset of rows to be published. Unlike static filters that send the same subset of rows to every Subscriber, parameterized row filters use a data value supplied by the Subscriber to send Subscribers different subsets of 
>     rows. For more information, see Parameterized Row Filters.**
> - Join filters, which are available    only with merge replication. Using  join filters, you can extend a row  filter from one published table to another. For more information, see  Join Filters.